# c# merge objects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

```
    Class Person
    {
        string Name
        int yesno
        int Change
        List<Cars> Personcars;
        houses Personhouses
    }

Person user1 = new Person()
Person user2 = new Person()

user1.Name = "userName"
user2.Name ="";

user2.cars[0] = new car("Mazda");
user1.cars[0] = new car("BMW");
```

i want to merge the objects so that user2 will take the name and the car from user1

user2 will have this values

user2.Name will be userName
user2.cars will hold the Mazda and the Bmw

thanks !

Comment: But what happens if the two merged Person s both have a name?
And more worryingly if this is modelling people; how do you plan on merging the actual people?

Comment: That code won't even compile in it's current state. I think you need to work on this question.

Comment: All of the variables in your Person class are private.  This can't be your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user2.Name = user1.Name;
user2.Personcars.AddRange(user1.Personcars);
```

---

You could add this as a method on the class itself:

```
public class Person
{
    List<Cars> _personcars;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    // what the hell is a yesno int? If it's 1 or 0 then just use a bool
    public int yesno { get; set; }
    public int Change { get; set; }
    public List<Cars> Personcars 
    {
        get
        {
            return _personcars ?? (_personCars = new List<Cars>());
        }
        set { _personcars = value; }
    }
    public Houses Personhouses { get; set; }

    public void Merge(Person person)
    {
        Name = person.Name;
        Personcars.AddRange(person.Personcars);
    }
}
```

Which will allow you to write something like this:

```
user2.Merge(user1);
```

Comment: +1 '// what the hell is a yesno int? If it's 1 or 0 then just use a bool
'

Comment: why even the need for int yesno?! If it's not a person, then why is it in the Person class?

Comment: @Code Monkey: Are you giving hunter a hard time about `int yesno`?  It wasn't his design decision; he just carried it forward from the question (with editorial comment, at that).

Comment: @phoog: No I am not. Simmer down fido.

Comment: My level of `yesno` is probably around `49`. I wish I could boil all people down, figuratively, into a `Name`, a collection of `Cars`, a `Houses`, plural, and with 2 seemingly meaningless integers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this extension methods

```
 public void Merge(this Person _person, Person source)
 {
     _person.Name = source.Name;
     if(_person.Cars !=null)
     {
        _person.Cars.AddRang(source.Cars);
     }
     else
     {
        _person.Cars = source.Cars;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Extension method is kinda unnecessary in this situation. You can just add it as a public method.